# Where can I find Aerith Project source code

Tags: java, swing, swingx

(This question may seem off-topic but its related to my project,so please don't downvote)

While reading **Filthy Rich Clients** by Romain Guy and Chet Hasse, I saw the description of Aerith project and when I googled it, I found that the project's source code can be downloaded at `http://www.aerith.dev.java.net/`.But this link is dead.

Do you, Java programmers,have that code or please can tell me the source where I can download it.

Thanks.Waiting for a favourable response.

Comment: java net moved through several loops ... see https://java.net/projects/aerith/

Comment: @kleopatra : After searching for another half hour I already reached to the link you provided and I also created an account to sign in but there is no link to download source code.There are four directories shown on the page and when I click on it ,it moves me to inside that folder.There is nothing like .zip or .rar that I can download

Comment: you probably need to checkout from svn, it was never released (afaik, not overly familiar with that particular project)

Comment: @kleopatra:Thanks I found it.But still I have to look each individual file by clickong on it.Wish it could have been better.Anyways,my task is done.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never. Have you checked this github repository - https://github.com/jsuper/aerith?